# How can I make an if statement that runs only if the turtle is NOT facing left?

Tags: javascript

I want the code to make the turtle turn Left when the left arrow key is pressed, unless it is already facing the left side of the screen. Then it just moves 10 pixels to the left.

I tried using `getDirection()` but since this is a function and not a variable, it didn't work. The variables `xloc` and `yloc` are numbers that are used in a `moveTo(xloc,yloc)`.

```
onEvent("gameScreen", "keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Left") {
      if(direction != 270){
        turnLeft();
      }else{
        xloc = xloc - 10;
      }
  }else if(event.key == "Up"){
      yloc = yloc - 10; 
  } 
var direction = getDirection();
```

I expected it to turn Left if it wasn't facing left. If it was, it was supposed to move 10 pixels to the left.

It actually spins in a circle, without moving in any direction.

Comment: Have you logged the value of `direction` on the line before you're checking it to see if the value truly is 270 when facing left?

Answer (score 0):

Then call the function inside your `if`.

```
onEvent("gameScreen", "keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Left") {
      if (getDirection() != 270) {
        turnLeft();
      } else {
        xloc = xloc - 10;
      } //...
```